# -webkit-filter in Stylus

Tags: stylus

Any chance to use this in stylus:

```
-webkit-filter: invert();
```

whitout

```
@css{
    .something {
        -webkit-filter: invert();
    }
}
```

Thnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be the [built-in function](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/bifs.html) `invert(color)`. The only solution I can think of (bar renaming the bif `invert`) is this:

```
.foo
  -webkit-filter unquote("invert()")
```